# Differences in Pane and Group in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

Suppose you have a block of code:

```
Pane pane = new Pane();
pane.getChildren().add(circle);
pane.getChildren().add(rectangle);

Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 400, 400);
```

Do you have to write pane.getChildren().add(===); every time you want to add something to the pane? Similarly, what is the difference in just writing ..

```
Pane pane = new Pane(circle, rectangle);

Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 400, 400);
```

As I have found that it does the exact same thing when I run the program and have the shapes display. Additionally, what is the different in writing with the use of Pane instead of:

```
Group root = new Group(circle, rectangle);

Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I have been looking online and have not seemed to have found anything that truly answers all of my questions.

Comment: java doc is your friend :)

Comment: One of the differences is stated in `Group`'s Javadoc: "_Such transforms and effects will NOT be included in this Group's layout bounds, **however if transforms and effects are set directly on children of this Group, those will be included in this Group's layout bounds**_". The same is not true of `Pane`.

Comment: @Slaw When I read that, I interpreted it as when you transform the window size, and when I messed with window size, it stayed the same. However, the same happened when I used pane, so I came to the conclusion window transformation is not what it is referring to. So what exactly do they mean by “transforms and effects?”

Comment: @kleopatra .. I knew it was coming lol. Once I hit “ask question,” I knew a comment about the docs were coming! Thank you for the help, though. I should get into a habit of actually reading them ;)

Comment: Okay, so if I want those things to be included, I need to use either Pane or the getChildren() of Group I suppose. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not really any difference between:

```java
Pane pane = new Pane(node1, node2);
```

And:

```java
Pane pane = new Pane();
pane.getChildren().add(node1);
pane.getChildren().add(node2);
```

Both approaches add the nodes the the children list of the layout. It's just that the first approach does this via the constructor; it's basically a shortcut for the second approach. However, the second approach can be used at any time so long as you have a reference to the layout.

---

Here are some differences between `Pane` and `Group`, though I can't promise this is an exhaustive list:

1. A `Group` will take into account any transforms or effects on its children when computing its layout bounds. This can have a profound affect on how your UI behaves when nodes are transformed (or have an effect applied on them). For instance, when you rotate a square the width and height grows and shrinks over time. If that square was in a `Group` then the `Group`'s width and height would correspondingly grow and shrink; a `Pane` would not do this.
2. The `Group` class extends directly from `Parent`. The `Pane` class extends from `Region` (and `Region` extends from `Parent`). That means a `Group` has none of the styling options provided by `Region` (e.g. backgrounds, borders, etc.).
3. The Javadoc of `Group` also says:

   > Any transform, effect, or state applied to a Group will be applied to all children of that group.

   I've never really experimented with this, so I'm not sure if this is truly different behavior than `Pane`.

Also, keep in mind that you'll typically want to use `Pane` or, more specifically, subclasses of `Pane`. This includes layouts such as `BorderPane`, `VBox`, and `StackPane`. Those layouts automatically manage their children to resize and position them according to the layout's rules. You can use nested layouts to achieve more complex designs. Personally, I've really only used `Group` if I want the behavior mentioned in point one above or if I'm using 3D shapes.

Comment: This is fantastic, it really helps! Thank you so much!